# HTTP Get request from api and load results to Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, https

I'm making a http GET request and will like to load results of API to Mysql db. code is below. My Db connection is working and i'm not getting any errors. I'm just not getting any results loaded into the db. what am I missing?

```js
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require ('mysql');
var express = require ('express')
let config = require ('./config.js')
let connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
var app = express ();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
require('dotenv').config()

// start api operation from  db
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'https://......,
  'headers': {
    'Cookie': ''
};
request(options, function(error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log('getting the goods');
});
// end api operation

//start body-parser configuration
app.use(bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
//end body-parser configuration

//create app server
var server = app.listen(3000,  "127.0.0.1", function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("i'm getting your data at http://%s:%s", host, port)

});
 // get data from customer api...
 var sql = `INSERT INTO dbname 
            (id, email, created_at, updated_at, first_name, last_name)
            VALUES ( '"+rec.body.id+"', '"+email+"', '"+created_at+"', '"+updated_at+"', '"+last_name+"', '"+first_name+"')`;
 var dbname = ['"id+"', '"+email+"', '"+created_at+"', '"+updated_at+"', '"+last_name+"', '"+first_name+"']

    console.log ("working")
   connection.query(sql, [dbname], (err, results, fields) => {
   if (err) {
  return console.error(err.message);
}
// get insrerted rows
   console.log('Row inserted:' + results.affectedRows);
});

 // close the database connection
  connection.end();
  console.log("disconnected")
```

Comment: Hi! I have a couple of questions: --- 1) Are you getting data from a third party API? If so, which API are you using? --- 2) What is your goal with Express? Is your goal to be able to go to a URL like `http://mywebsite.com/apidata` and have it load the data?

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your response. yes, i'm getting data from shopify's api. I want to upload all of my new customers that setup an account to my db. It would be nice to have that feature with express, but it is not a requirement.